# Intercept HTTP responses on an HTTPS server in Node.JS and Express

Tags: node.js, express

I'm just starting with node.js and express and I'm doing a simple HTTPS server. I've been working with nginx for some time and when I make an HTTP request to an HTTPS endpoint I get a "400 Bad Request" error. However, when using node.js the request never finishes.

How can I intercept an HTTP request in Express to be able to generate the "400 Bad Request" response?

This is my code:

```
var express = require('express'); 
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

var tls_options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('certs/server.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('certs/server.crt'),
  ca: fs.readFileSync('certs/ca.crt'),
  requestCert: true,
};

var app = express();
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.json({ message: 'Checkpoint!!' });  
});

app.use('/', router);

var secureServer = https.createServer(tls_options, app);
secureServer.listen(port);
console.log('Listening on port ' + port);
```

Until now the only thing I've been able to use is getting a 'connection' event every time a request arrives to the server:

```
secureServer.on('connection', function (stream) {
   console.log('someone connected!');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done. In fact, an HTTP request to an HTTPS socket ends after the default 120secs TLS handsahke timeout. This way I can end the request without waiting. I include the solution I used just for future references if anything needs the same functionality.

```
var secureServer = https.createServer(options, app);
secureServer.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('data', function(data) {
    var first_line = data.toString().split('\r\n')[0];
    var pattern = /\bhttp\/1\.[01]$\b/i;
    if (pattern.test(first_line)) {
        var headers = {};
        headers['Date'] = new Date().toUTCString();
        headers['Connection'] = 'close';
        var headers_string = '';
        for (var name in headers) {
            headers_string = headers_string + '\r\n' + name + ': ' + headers[name];
        }
        socket.end('HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request' + headers_string);
    }
});
```

Comment: This approach worked with Node v0.10.x, but it's not working after v0.12.x... any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

There isn't a way of starting both HTTP and HTTPS servers on the same port.  What most people do is either:

Start two servers (one HTTP and one HTTPS) on different ports, and redirect the HTTP traffic to HTTPS.  Using Express it would mean the additional code:

```
// create two ports, one for HTTP and one for HTTPS
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
var httpsPort = 8081;

// redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var hostname;

    if (!req.secure) {
        hostname = req.get("host").split(":")[0];
        return res.redirect(["https://", hostname, ":", httpsPort, req.url].join(""));
    }
    next();
});

app.listen(port);  // listen on HTTP
https.createServer(tls_options, app).listen(httpsPort);  // listen on HTTPS
```

Or they use nginx or apache to handle outside connections (both HTTP and HTTPS) and redirect traffic to the Node server (which can then just run on HTTP).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I know that I can't start 2 servers on the same port, what I was meaning is that even if I only have an HTTPS server, if I send an HTTP request to this port I don't get any error and the request never ends. I'm just looking for a way of avoiding this.